# brew install sshfs

Tags: ssh, homebrew, sshfs

I'm trying to install `sshfs` using homebrew. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

```
~/Desktop> brew install sshfs
==> Installing sshfs dependency: fuse4x
==> Downloading https://github.com/fuse4x/fuse/tarball/fuse4x_0_9_1
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/fuse4x-0.9.1.tgz
==> autoreconf --force --install
aclocal: error: aclocal: file '/usr/local/share/aclocal/mysql.m4' does not exist
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
==> Build Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.2
HEAD: e3d609903576d1902240532b27b8e136d93af42b
CPU: 8-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.7.4-x86_64
Xcode: 4.3.3
CLT: 1.0.0.9000000000.1.1249367152
X11: 2.6.4 @ /usr/X11
CC: /usr/bin/clang
CXX: /usr/bin/clang++ => /usr/bin/clang
LD: /usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch i386 -arch x86_64
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch i386 -arch x86_64
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.12.2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/include -isystem /usr/local/include
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.12.2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/lib -L/usr/local/lib -arch i386 -arch x86_64
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: 10.7
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
Error: Failed executing: autoreconf --force --install (fuse4x.rb:18)
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12266
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13647
Otherwise, this may help you fix or report the issue:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/bug-fixing-checklist
~/Desktop> sudo brew install sshfs
Password:
Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install'
```

Answer (score 4):

It gave you two links to existing issues related to the error you are receiving. You should visit those links and see if they help you resolve the issue:

- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12266
- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13647

You should not be using sudo when installing things via homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly the same problem and solved it by first running
 brew update
as suggested here:
 https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/bug-fixing-checklist